# Export all orders to an excel/CSV

Tags: sitecore-commerce

Is there a way to export all orders to an excel from BizFX interface or Postman?
I am using Sitecore commerce 9.0.2

Comment: Have you considered using Sitecore PowerShell Extensions to query the data and then save to CSV?

Comment: No @MichaelWest. Is it possible this way?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible to export orders to an excel OOTB.

Only what you can do is run postman request:

> GET {{ServiceHost}}/{{ShopsApi}}/Orders

which will return all existing orders in Sitecore Commerce engine in JSON format.

Comment: I guess then it will be easy, just save the JSON in File and in Excel, under the data tab, select Get data > from file > from JSON > select the JSON file. It will create an excel file :)

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat I did try this but after converting the data to excel, the format of the data is not readable. the data is all jumbled up.

Comment: @HimanshuAgarwalm It is because orders JSON is nested object, but Excel expects linear (tabular) format. What information do you need to have in your Excel (what columns)? I can share my simple C# console app code, that I use for convert JSON from commerce to CSV table.

Comment: From my opinion, the easiest way is to implement custom parser for json file, which will grab only data what you need. The best solutions is to implement custom commerce api for generate csv file (in the same way how it works for private coupons)